# Improve an existing loop and delay in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply, sapply

I am looking for a different way to improve my loop. I have been given a function `patient_ID_extract()` taking a patient_number and it would pull out the records from the API key. The API key will reset the limit at 300 every 5 minutes.

My first working approach is to write a loop and set a time delay. This will take the patient number one by one from a collection of ID strings.

```
for ( i in patient_number){ 
  patients[[i]] <- patient_ID_extract(i, api_key)
  Sys.sleep(1.5)
}
```

I am wondering if there's a way I can extract 300 records per time, delay 5 minutes and run extract 300 records again.

```
patient_number <- c("10523563", "08989388", "12338490", "11362265", "08732885", "06464116", 
        "02841570", "09966472", "11260599", "06797991", "11047641", "09538121", 
        "01298039", "00875727", "SC464438", "11361061", "SC294938", "02450551", 
        "09447238", "12229772", "10562525", "11834746", "08226516", "11480020", 
        "SC255490", "11794931", "01298989", "09782645")
```

Comment: Please explain: is it the target app (fed by api_key value) which refuses more than 300 requests every 5  minutes?   If so, just run a loop from `last_index_value+1` to `last_index_value+301` , then `Sys.sleep(300)`

Comment: There's a parameter for patient_number in the API. It refuses more than 300 requests within 5 minutes. If you take 300, you then have to wait for 5 mins for another 300. Where do I add the `last_index_value+301`? @CarlWitthoft

Comment: Basically make a double - loop, with the inner loop running in chunks of 300, and the outer loop incrementing the "multiplier" for the index